# Fatal error: Call to undefined function isLoggedIn()

Tags: php

I keep getting the error"Fatal error: Call to undefined function isLoggedIn() in /home/********/public_html/login.php on line 2".

index.php

```
<?php

$page = "Home";

require_once "header.php"; 
 //content

global $prostats;  

?>  
//Some html stuff
<?php

 require_once "footer.php";

?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
if (!isLoggedIn())
{
    // user is not logged in.
    if (isset($_POST['cmdlogin']))
    {
        // retrieve the username and password sent from login form & check the login.
        if (checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
        {
            echo '<ul class="pull-right"><li>';
            show_userbox ();
            echo '</li></ul>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<ul class="pull-right">
            <li class="signUp"><a href="http://elitekastdev.com/register.php">Sign Up</a></li>';
            echo '<li class="logIn"><a>Log In</a><p>Incorrect Login information</p><ul><li>';
            show_loginform ();
            echo '</li></ul></li></ul>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // User is not logged in and has not pressed the login button
        // so we show him the loginform
         echo '<ul class="pull-right">
         <li class="signUp"><a href="http://elitekastdev.com/register.php">Sign Up</a></li>';
         echo '<li class="logIn"><a>Log In</a><ul><li>';
         show_loginform ();
         echo '</li></ul></li></ul>';
    }

}
else
{
    // The user is already loggedin, so we show the userbox.
    echo '<ul class="pull-right"><li>';
    show_userbox ();
    echo '</li></ul>';
}
?>
```

footer.php

```
</body>
<footer>
    <p>&copy;<a href="***" title="***">***</a> 2014 - <?php echo date("Y"); ?> All Rights Reserved</p>
</footer>
</html>
```

header.php

```
<?php

//error_reporting(0); // we don't want to see errors on screen
// Start a session
session_start();
require_once ("user/db_connect.inc.php"); // include the database connection
require_once ("user/functions/functions.inc.php"); // include all the functions
$seed="0dAfghRqSTgx"; // the seed for the passwords
$domain =  "example.com"; // the domain name without http://www.

$prostat = "Offline";

if (function_exists('isLoggedIn')) {

}
else
{
  function isLoggedIn()
  {
      if (isset($_SESSION['loginid']) && isset($_SESSION['username']))
      {
          return true; // the user is logged in
      }
      else
      {
          return false; // not logged in
      }
      return false;
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example | <?php echo $page; ?></title>     
            <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://example.com/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/js/buttons.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
<header>
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="pull-left">
          <li><a href="http://example.com">Example</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Coming Soon!</a></li>
        </ul>
          <?php
            include "http://example.com/login.php";
          ?>
```

However any of the functions I have don't work, I you need the functions and all that I will update this with the links to it because there is just too much code as it is!

I would like to know why I can include/require the .php files but I cannot call functions from them?
What is your source?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `include "login.php";`? You don't need a full URL if you're including a local file

Comment: i would expect, that the function is only valid within the else-block, not outside the else block

Comment: What is the reason for conditionally defining `isLoggedIn()`? Can you not ensure that it is only defined once? That's the source of your problem here.

Comment: The code is only there to try and fix it, the acctual comes from functions.inc.php
`if (!function_exists('isLoggedIn'))  
{  
function isLoggedIn()  
  {  
      if (isset($_SESSION['loginid']) &&    isset($_SESSION['username']))  
      {  
          return true; // the user is logged in  
      }  
      else  
      {  
          return false; // not logged in  
      }  
      return false;  
  }  
} `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have URL include wrappers enabled in your php.ini file, including a URL will **cause a fatal error.** see: http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include)

Assuming the login.php is actually on the same server as the rest of your scripts you should include it using the correct local path and **NOT A HTTP URL** use either an absolute or relative path; PHP will also use any paths configured in your php.ini config.

more info :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

When you intentionally **include a HTTP URL** as you do in your code:

```
include "http://example.com/login.php";
```

You will usually **not have access to the functions** within the login.php file because the file will be processed on the target server first and you will be including the 'output' from that script instead.

Comment: It includes the files, all the html and some php however it is the functions that don't work, There is nothing wrong with the `include "./login.php"` file or script, it is the `require_once "http://example.com/user/functions/functions.inc.php";`

Comment: Same applies, if you require or include a URL rather than a path you will get a fatal error if php is not configured to allow URL includes; otherwise you may or may not get the desired function code; in most cases you will just get the processed output of the target file on the target server if the target server is configured to serve .php files as php.

Comment: Ahhhh, I understand now, just took me some realization, Late night I guess.